# Spring Hibernate - Set static final String to indicate the schema of Hibernate entity

Tags: spring, hibernate

I have domain objects mapped as Hibernate entities stored in 2 distinct schemas of an Oracle database. Unfortunately, one of this schema has not the same name between Test and Prod environment database.

To avoid changing manually the schema in the code each time I deploy on such or such environment, my idea was to use a Spring property placeholder to get values in a properties file depending of the environment. Then using MethodInvokingFactoryBean to set those properties in useful static Utility class.

Spring's conf setting values of static variables depending of properties read in a properties file with Spring's PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer :

```
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean">
    <property name="targetClass" value="com.company.app.Schemas" />
    <property name="targetMethod" value="setSchemaNames" />
    <property name="arguments">
        <props>
            <prop key="schema1">${schema1_name}</prop>
            <prop key="schema2">${schema2_name}</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Then class hosting static schemas names :

```
public class Schemas {

    public static String SCHEMA1;

    public static String SCHEMA2;

    public static void setSchemaNames(Map<String, String> schemaNames) {
        Schemas.SCHEMA1 = schemaNames.get("schema1"); 
        Schemas.SCHEMA2 = schemaNames.get("schema2");
    }

}
```

Fianlly Hibenate mapping :

```
@Entity
@Table(schema = Schemas.SCHEMA1, name = "item")
public class Item {
  ...
}
```

However to set the schema attribute of the @Table Hibernate annotation, I cannot use "static" variables, I must use "final static" variables (constant). So the last piece of code above does not compile.

I did not succeed to set "final static" variable with Spring's MethodInvokingFactoryBean. How could I do ?

Answer (score 0):

In theory you could create a class which accesses the `public static final` fields and us reflection to make them accessible and set the value.

```
Field field = ReflectionUtils.findField(Schemas.class, "SCHEMA1");
field.setAccessible(true);
ReflectionUtils.setField(field, target, "MySchema");
```

However even with that in place it will never work. The constants in the `Item` class will be inlined, at compile time, with the actual value. If you would decompile your `Item` class it would look something like the following.

```
@Entity
@Table(schema = null, name = "item")
public class Item {
  ...
}
```

That is simply the way constants work in java (or better the java compiler).

> I have domain objects mapped as Hibernate entities stored in 2 distinct schemas of an Oracle database. Unfortunately, one of this schema has not the same name between Test and Prod environment database

This might help you in your solution. Basically in your entities which have the constant schema in test en prod define the schema. For the other entities (different schema in test en prod) don't define a schema but simply set the `hibernate.default_schema` property in your configuration.